# Sign URL for Upload to S3, Javascript & Boto

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon AWS from Javascript with a signed URL obtained from a django api where I sign it with the help of Boto. This is my line in python:

```
url = conn.generate_url(300, 'PUT', settings.AWS_VIDEO_BUCKET, key, headers={'Content-Length': '19448423'}, force_http = True )
```

Using the URL generated from this, I can post to S3 with CURL like so:

```
curl -v --request PUT --upload-file video.mp4 "http://some_signed_url"
```

What does not work though, is using this URL to PUT a file to Amazon AWS via Javascript. Debugging with a proxy reveals a broken pipe error, while CURL would give me the regular Amazon Access Denied XML if something went wrong. This is my javascript code (file is a JS File object):

```
var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', file );

$.ajax({
  url: 'signed_url',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  type: 'PUT',
  success: function(data){
    console.log("success");
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data.responseText);
  }
});
```

Any ideas where to go from here? Maybe I'm not including all the required headers in the signing process, or FormData is not the right way to go.

Comment: have you considered the Same Origin Policy?

Comment: Yes, that's taken care of. I'd get a different type of error from a preflighted options request. But that passes, I can see that in the debugging proxy.